# Android googlemaps v2 finish loading event or callback

Tags: android, events, callback, loading, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to do something after the google maps has loaded(maptiles have been filled) is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: I'm interested in this too. Nothing in the API documentation AFAIK caters for it. There is something in ```MarkerDemoActivity.java``` from the SDK around line 198 where ```mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() { ... )     }
            }); ``` is used to check if "..the map has a size." I've tried playing around with this and have had no success.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [qubz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496625/qubz), the ViewTreeObserver can be used to achieve a callback after the loading of the map has completed, so the user will get e.g. the correct location right after start-up:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // This is a small hack to enable a onMapLoadingCompleted-functionality to the user.
    final View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map_fragment).getView();
    if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            // We use the new method when supported
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            // We check which build version we are using.
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
                // Send notification that map-loading has completed.
                onMapFinishedLoading();
            }
        });
    }
}

protected void onMapFinishedLoading() {
    // Do whatever you want to do. Map has completed loading at this point.
    Log.i(TAG, "Map finished loading.");
    GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map_fragment))
                    .getMap();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not always returning a loaded map, but only the visible and measured view. Currently I have not found any way, but posting a delayed Runnable with x-milliseconds  delay.

Comment: First: What do you want to achieve? If you want to zoom to a particular start position for example, this finishedLoading() method will work fine. Loading tiles will be async in the background all the time, when the user scrolls, so how meaningful would be a callback if a certain part is fully loaded? Btw: Performing a delay is extremely dangerous, because either you block your user too long (unresponsive app) or you are too short and the data will not be loaded ready. Since this will depend on the speed of the data-connection this is a clear No-Go!

Comment: Sometimes `getViewTreeObserver` is not alive at listener even if is alive at before `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`.